# Spring 2.4.2 spring.hazelcast.config ignored?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

I have added the JVM start the parameter:

```
-Dspring.hazelcast.config=classpath:hazelcast2.xml
```

but in log I see

```
08:54:59.849 [I] [main           ] AbstractConfigLocator.log:49 - Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from the classpath.
```

Inside the jar does exist this **hazelcast2.xml**
I puttet also outside of the jar inside start folder these file.

Why he falls back to internal **hazelcast.xml** ?

I can put a changed **hazlecast.xml** outside the jar and this is respected.
But how I can change the hazlecast.xml file name using JVM parameters like documented in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.hazelcast

I put the parameter in application.properties without success.

spring boot 2.4.2
hazelcast 4.1.1

Comment: Which version of Hazelcast are you using?

Comment: hazelcast 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one?

```
-Dhazelcast.client.config=classpath:hazelcast2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

the searched parameter is:

```
-Dhazelcast.config=classpath:hazelcast2.xml
```

reason is in
com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator.locateEverywhere()

```
    public boolean locateEverywhere() {
        return locateFromSystemPropertyOrFailOnUnacceptedSuffix()
                || locateInWorkDir()
                || locateOnClasspath()
                || locateDefault();
    }
```

- The issue here is, that **locateOnClasspath** and **locateOnClasspath** only search for **hazelcast.xml** and **locateFromSystemPropertyOrFailOnUnacceptedSuffix** is loading from a env variable with name defined in com.hazelcast.internal.config.DeclarativeConfigUtil.SYSPROP_MEMBER_CONFIG = "hazelcast.config";
- I would see it as a bug. But maybe there was an intention to do it so.

I found also this docu: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/configuration/configuring-declaratively.html